# How to Update cell value based on user form input and unique id in VBA excel

Tags: vba

I have a sheet with name "Current Stock" where i put the items inventory like opening stock, quantity issued, qty-purchase and balance, i just need to update the "quantity issued" column of item which I issued through Issue Item Form corresponding to their "item code" in "Current Stock" Sheet. what is the code for vba

Comment: did you try something already? if yes, please post your code.

Comment: A picture (and some code) tells more than 1000 words ...